# Command line tools won't update (keeps on coming back)

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, software-update

I am using OS X 10.12.3 and the Managed Software Center keeps on inviting me to update "Command line tools" version 8.2. If I do update it, the message comes back a little later.

Is there any way to debug or fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion 1 : Reset the App Store**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
3. Relaunch the App Store
4. Choose the menu item **Debug** → **Reset Application**.

**Suggestion 2 : Delete duplicate entry in the update logs**

This might happen because of duplicate entries in the updates log at
`~/Library/Application Support/App Store/updatejournal.plist`.

Convert `updatejournal.plist` from binary by entering `plutil -convert xml1` then drag the `updatejournal.plist` from Finder into Terminal.
This is an XML file where you need to delete the entry inside the scope of `<dict>` that says something like :

```
    <dict>
    ...
    <string>Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10)</string>
    ...
    </dict>
```

A detailed write-up can be found in the post
[Appstore multiple update of the same application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151545/appstore-multiple-update-of-the-same-application/151578#151578).

Comment: Thanks very much. I think the problem was caused by installing mactex via brew. It then at some point recommended I did xcode-select --install after which this problem appeared.

Comment: I followed the instructions you linked to and deleted one of the two entries relating to Command Line Tools. It appears to have worked so far.

Comment: If this solution was accepted, why was the bounty awarded elsewhere?

Comment: The honest answer is that I made a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: For the future: There's no need to award manually the bounty - it's awarded automatically to the accepted answer when the bounty-period elapses. The accepted answer can be changed at any time, so many posters wait with awarding the bounty.

Comment: Got it.  I thought it only awarded half of the points automatically if you didn't do it manually.

Comment: Only if there is no accepted answer, then half the bounty is awarded to the first highest-voted answer, provided it has at least 2 votes.

Answer (score 2):

See if you can follow the below steps but for "**Managed Software Center**" in particular from this list or the equivalent list area per your version of Mac OS X.

> To stop Software Update in Mac OS X from pestering you about a
>   particular package being available, all you need to do is the
>   following:
>
> - Select the package in the Software Update screen
> - Navigate to the ‘Update’ menu and selecting “Ignore Update” (see    screenshot below) while the item is to ignore is selected
>
> [image]
>
> If you accidentally ignore a package you do want, or you change your
>   mind later, no problem – simply go to the Software Updates main menu
>   and select “Reset Ignored Updates” to reset the list and set the
>   packages for Mac OS X again.
>
> <sub>[source](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/08/ignore-mac-software-update-packages/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you but there must be an installation problem or the message wouldn't come back after a few minutes. I would like to fix it rather than ignore it.